# Properties 'toLowerCase' and 'includes' error Vue.js vuetify

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

im trying to achieve multiple filters on vuetify datatables, everything is working fine until the method that validates the search which shows the following error

[image]

[image]

template:

```
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
      <v-row class="pa-6">
        <!-- Filter for dessert name-->
        <v-text-field v-model="contactoFilterValue" type="text" label="Contacto"></v-text-field>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="6">
      <v-row class="pa-6">
        <!-- Filter for calories -->
        <v-select
                :items="empresaLists"
                item-text="nombre" item-value="nombre"
                v-model="empresaFilterValue"
                label="Empresa"
        ></v-select>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

script:

```
data: () => ({
  contactoFilterValue: '',
  empresaFilterValue: null,
},

computed: { 
  headers(){
    return[
    {text: '', value: 'viewmore', sortable: false },
    {text: 'Empresa',align: 'start',value: 'empresa', filter: this.empresaFilter,},
    {text: 'Contacto',value: 'contacto', filter: this.contactoFilter,},
    {text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
  ]},
},
    
methods: { 
      contactoFilter(value) {
        if (!this.contactoFilterValue) {
          return true;
        }
        return value.toLowerCase().includes(this.contactoFilterValue.toLowerCase());
      },
      empresaFilter(value) {
        if (!this.empresaFilterValue) {
          return true;
        }
        return value === this.empresaFilterValue;
      },
    }
```

it seems that this line is not working as it should, does anyone know a solution?

**return value.toLowerCase().includes(this.contactoFilterValue.toLowerCase());**

Comment: try to check if value is not empty.... if (!this.contactoFilterValue || value == undefined || value == null) {

Answer (score 0):

On this line, you're setting `filter` to the function `contactoFilter`, but you don't supply the parameter `value`:

```
 {text: 'Contacto',value: 'contacto', filter: this.contactoFilter,},
```

I'm not sure what you're intending. Either supply a value like `this.contactoFilter('foo')` or use a different variable to assign as `filter`.